# Change in weight by the change in mass of Earth and its radius

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, weight

If the mass of Earth is four-times bigger, and the radius of Earth is two-times smaller, what would be my new weight compared to my current weight?

Answer (score 1):

First, answer the following question. If the mass of the earth is $M$, and the radius is $R$, then what would your current weight be if your mass is $m$ and the gravitational constant is $G$? In other words, what upward normal force must the scale apply to your body to counteract the downward force of gravity?

Once you have this answer, do the calculation again for $4M$ and $\frac{R}{2}$ and compare.

Comment: a. 16-times bigger ?